# php no esta escriviendo csv

Tags: php, csv

e intentado escrivir un archivo csv con php, de alguna forma no esta escribiendo nada y quisiera saber que podria ser, si me recomiendan un editor de php para linux, pues estoy trabajando con el editor nano desde la consola, el codigo es

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$fechaSolicitacion = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$nombreEvento = $_POST["nombreEvento"];
$Solicitante = $_POST["Solicitante"];
$emailSolicitante = $_POST["emailSolicitante"];
$servicio = $_POST["servicio"];
$fechaEvento =$_POST["fechaEvento"];
$horaFin = $_POST["horaFin"];
$horaInicio = $_POST["horaInicio"];
$organiza = $_POST["organiza"];
$nombreResponsable = $_POST["nombreResponsable"];
$cargo = $_POST["cargo"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$responsableTecnico = $_POST["responsableTecnico"];
$emailTecnico = $_POST["emailTecnico"];
$iniciohora = (int) substr($horaInicio, 0, 2);
$finhora = (int) substr($horaFin, 0, 2);
$iniciominutos = (int) substr($horaInicio, 3, 4);
$finminutos = (int) substr($horaFin, 3, 4);
$minutos = $finminutos - $iniciominutos;
if ($minutos < 0){
$minutos = $minutos*(-1);
}
$duracion = ($finhora - $iniciohora)*60 + $minutos;
echo $duracion . '<br \>';
$iniciohora = $iniciohora + 5;
$hora = $fechaEvento . " " .  $iniciohora . ":" . $iniciominutos;
echo "hora: " . $hora. '<br \>';
$hora = strtotime($hora);
$hora = gmdate("Y M d H:i:s T", $hora);
$fechaSolicitacion = strtotime($fechaSolicitacion);
$fechaSolicitacion = gmdate("Y M d H:i:s T", $fechaSolicitacion);
$csv_line = array($nombreEvento, $Solicitante, $emailSolicitante, $servicio, 
$fechaEvento, $horazoom, $duracion, $organiza, $nombreResponsable, $cargo, 
$telefono, $celular, $responsableTecnico, $emailTecnico); 
$path = 'reuniones.csv';
$fop = fopen($path, 'w');
foreach ($csv_line as $line){
fputcsv($fop, $line);
}
rewind($fop);
fclose($fop);
?>
```

todos los archivos estan y existen en /var/www/html
el php se ejecuta desde un html, se que recojo los datos del formulario de html. el sistema operativo es ubuntu.

Comment: El problema es que `fputcsv` espera como segundo parámetro un array y tú le estás pasando cada elemento del array. No sé exactamente lo que hay en `$csv_line`, pero si tú quitas el `foreach` dejando solamente esto: `fputcsv($fop, $csv_line);` te escribirá toda la línea en el archivo (los valores del array separados por coma. Si no es eso lo que quieres debes dar más detalles y mostrar cómo está constituido el array que le estás pasando.

Comment: le quite el foreach y no paso nada, es mas intente con con vector ficitcio array('1', '2', '3') y no paso nada. El array esta construido de un formulario extraido de un html, tiene valores String como de tiempo,

Comment: Yo hice una prueba con este código: `$csv_line = array('a','b');
$path = 'reuniones.csv';
$fop = fopen($path, 'w');
fputcsv($fop, $csv_line);
rewind($fop);
fclose($fop);` y me funciona. Aparece esto escrito en el archivo: `a,b` ... Deberías revisar si no es un problema de permisos en el mismo archivo. Supongo que el archivo existe en la ruta donde ejecutas el script.

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código y funciona como te dije en comentario.

Puede que en tu caso el archivo no exista o que no tenga permiso de escritura. Puedes controlar ambas situaciones haciendo algo como esto:

```
$msg="";
$path = 'reuniones.csv';
if (file_exists($path)){
    if (is_writable($path)){
        $csv_line = array('a','b');
        $fop = fopen($path, 'w');
        fputcsv($fop, $csv_line);
        rewind($fop);
        fclose($fop);
        $msg="Archivo modificado correctamente".PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        $msg.="No se puede escribir en el archivo".PHP_EOL;
    }
}else{
    $msg.="El archivo no existe".PHP_EOL;
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: cabe recordar que se deben otorgar los permisos al php de ejecución y de escritura al csv.

Comment: para agregar una nueva linea simplemente cambian 'w' por 'a' en fopen